# Access values in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I access a variable value from one stateful widget class to another stateful widget class. Also both widget classes are in different .dart files.

This is screen.dart having the variable "List points". I want to use it in home.dart.

```
class Draw extends StatefulWidget {
  const Draw({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DrawState createState() => _DrawState();
}

class _DrawState extends State<Draw> {
  List points = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
        Offset localPos = details.localPosition;
        setState(() {
          if (localPos.dx >= 0 &&
              localPos.dx <= MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8 &&
              localPos.dy >= 0 &&
              localPos.dy <= MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5)
            points.add(localPos);
          else {
            points.add(null);
          }
        });
      },
      onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
        points.add(null);
      },
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: Painter(points: points),
      ),
    );
  }
}
...rest of code
```

This is home.dart

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.restore_page,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        title: Text(
          "Digit Recognizer",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white, border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
              child: Draw(),
            ),
...rest of code
```

I want to access the "points" from screen.dart variable inside the floatingActionButton's on pressed() function in home.dart.

Comment: Could you show how you are navigating between the 2 widgets? Please provide some code so that we can know about how u navigate and whether the variable is static or dynamic

Comment: if you are new to flutter then kindly refer to this video ==> https://youtu.be/l3KnuUmlr-w.  This will clear all your doubts.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal I have added code.

Comment: @UrDistraction here's the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place both of these widgets in the same file and then create points as a global Variable, so

```
List points = [];

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            print(points);
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.restore_page,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        title: Text(
          "Digit Recognizer",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white, border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
              child: Draw(),
            ),
...rest of code


class Draw extends StatefulWidget {
  const Draw({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DrawState createState() => _DrawState();
}

class _DrawState extends State<Draw> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
        Offset localPos = details.localPosition;
        setState(() {
          if (localPos.dx >= 0 &&
              localPos.dx <= MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8 &&
              localPos.dy >= 0 &&
              localPos.dy <= MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5)
            points.add(localPos);
          else {
            points.add(null);
          }
        });
      },
      onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
        points.add(null);
      },
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: Painter(points: points),
      ),
    );
  }
}
...rest of code
```

Usually I would not even create a different statefulw idget for this case but I am guessing you are doing it for some other reason. Creating a global variable allows it to be accessed from anywhere\

A better way of implementing the first answer might be this but you'll have to see if it works.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Widget drawWidget = Container();
   
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    drawWidget = Draw();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            print(drawWidget.points);
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.restore_page,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        title: Text(
          "Digit Recognizer",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white, border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
              child: drawWidget,
            ),
...rest of code
```

And in drawWidget

```
class Draw extends StatefulWidget {
  const Draw({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  List points = [];
  @override
  _DrawState createState() => _DrawState();
}

class _DrawState extends State<Draw> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
        Offset localPos = details.localPosition;
        setState(() {
          if (localPos.dx >= 0 &&
              localPos.dx <= MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8 &&
              localPos.dy >= 0 &&
              localPos.dy <= MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5)
            widget.points.add(localPos);
          else {
            widget.points.add(null);
          }
        });
      },
      onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
        widget.points.add(null);
      },
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: Painter(points: widget.points),
      ),
    );
  }
}
...rest of code
```

Hope it helps
The print statement in each code shows how to access

Answer (score 0):

```
class stful1{
  //create state method
}
class stful1 extends state{
   //Widget build method
   //data is actual data you want to send
   Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute((context)=>stful2(data)))
}


//stful2
class stful2{
  //accept data in constructor
  dataType data;
  stful2(this.data);
  //create state method
}
class stful2 extends state{
   //Widget build method
  //access like widget.data
}
```

Comment: As you can see from the code, his implementation is very different in the sense he is displaying the stateful widget inside another

Comment: At time when I commented the sample code, he didn't provided his actual Code.